# Is there a pattern or gem for saving options in a serialized column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an options column which is serialized. I plan to store user preferences in it, but I can't find any detailed writing covering this from form building to controller/model changes. I am wondering if there is a known pattern for this, or is there a gem covering this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [**has_serialized**](https://github.com/ramontayag/has_serialized) gem at the end. Basically after specifying each of the field within the serialized one, you can access each of these as a native attribute.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_serialized :options,
    :notification_comment => false,
    :notification_message => false,
```

This way I can easily use it with form builder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `serialize :column_name`  in model,and in form either you pass array of data or if you want to store hash you can use serialize hash

Comment: about the form, how to create an input element for these options, and how does these params turn into the option hash?

Comment: What kind of input data type is used,Like if you are using checkbox then pretty straight forward checkbox with same name with array as db.

Comment: You can see https://gist.github.com/2235072 and also visit for more reference http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: thanks I didn't know one can do that. However to make it simpler now I use the __has_serialized__ gem.